# Caching multi-dimensional data?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, caching

(This is a question about optimization and performance, I want to lay the ground work here, then at the end are my questions.)

I'm coding an RESTful API in Ruby on Rails that returns policy data about a video as it exists in a region. An example policy might be "Video **#1**: **ShowWithAds** in **US**" or "Video **#2**: **Block** in **MX**."

I need to return data for two views:

1. "Show all videos for **US** with **Block**" returns list of policies for each video that has been blocked in the US.
2. "Show policy for Video **#1** in **MX**" returns the policy for video #1 in MX. i.e. "**ShowAds**"

Here's what my tables look like:

**Video**

- VideoID (string)
- Title

**VideoPolicy** (acts as JOIN table for Video and Policy)

- VideoID (FK to Video, string)
- Country (string)
- PolicyID (FK to Policy, int)

[Indexes on 'VideoID/Country' and 'Country/PolicyID']

**Policy**

- PolicyID (int)
- Name (string)

And so the DB queries for each of the views above look like:

1. "Select from VideoPolicy where Country = US AND PolicyID = 1"
2. "Select from VideoPolicy where Country = US AND VideoID = 2"

Pretty simple tables/queries overall. When this system begins scale, say arbitrarily I have 500,000 videos, each with policies for 200 countries, that means the **Video** table becomes *500,000 rows*, the **VideoPolicy** table becomes (500,000 * 200 =) *100 million rows*,and the **Policy** table is just *4 rows*.

**Here's where my questions start.**

1. Although it lacks a primary key, assuming I have the proper indexes on that JOIN table **VideoPolicy**, will my queries above still run efficiently?
2. If so, I'm happy enough with the DB end. However, as a web app, I don't want to hit the DB every-time for policies, so I want to implement caching. What kind of key should I be using for my cache (assuming the payload is a **VideoPolicy**), in order to satisfy these two views/queries?
3. Is there any Rails magic I can take advantage of here?
4. Am I missing any other potential performance bottlenecks?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think compound indexes on (country, video_id) and (country, policy_id) will solve the problem, it's an easy operation on your set. Do you really need caching here - not sure, in case of db performance hit you could shard your data by country.

What about caching - you could cache concrete pages (like use view cache)